# what i need for invoke various actions and view in my layour main

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

well i trying build a website on ZendFrameWork 2 i want execute various actions in my layout main like a fild of search, or a form for loguin etc. each one of this i believe should are in views diferents with your actions, how i do for references this actions with your views that will return this element for i put where i want in my layout. like the helper $this->content; where it return the context view and action no just the view with no function, which are the best way for i do this or a way alternative

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need are view partials. You can read on view partials [in the ZF2 official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html).

You have to create your partials and then you register them under your `template_map` inside the `view_manager` config.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    //...
    'template_map' => array(
        'my/form' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/form.phtml',
        'my/partial' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/partial.phtml',
    )
),
```

Then in every layout you can simply embed them like this:

```
echo $this->partial('my/form');
echo $this->partial('my/partial');
```

If you need to pass variables to your partials you can pass a second argument:

```
echo $this->partial('my/form', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```